# I want to open the same URL every hour and take a screencapture of the opened webpage

Tags: applescript, screen-capture

I want to take a screen capture of a dynamic webpage. Content changes every hour of the day.
My script works fine but:
 1. I want to make sure the script is active while the iMac (OS X
    Yosemite Version 10.10.5) is in sleep modus or when the screen saver is active.
 2. Second problem is that the screen capture must be my desired webpage
    and not the active window.

```
set dFolder to "~/Desktop/screencapture/"
do shell script ("mkdir -p " & dFolder)
set i to 0
repeat 24 times
    do shell script "open -a Safari http://www.lipsum.com/"
    do shell script ("screencapture " & dFolder & "frame-" & i & ".png")
    delay 3600 -- Wait for 3600 seconds.
    set i to i + 1
end repeat
```

Comment: Did not have the time to try it. Tx for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can do what you want with the tool you have chosen. I think you need to use `webkit2png`.

Go to GitHub and download the `webkit2png` script from [here](https://github.com/paulhammond/webkit2png/). It is just a Python script in a single file. You will need to edit it around line 420 so it looks like this (there are 3 lines added in the middle):

```
# Hide the dock icon (needs to run before NSApplication.sharedApplication)
AppKit.NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary()['LSBackgroundOnly'] = '1'

# Handles ATS HTTPS requirement introduced in El Cap
if options.ignore_ssl_check:
    AppKit.NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary()['NSAppTransportSecurity'] = dict(NSAllowsArbitraryLoads = True)

app = AppKit.NSApplication.sharedApplication()
```

Now you can download your website whether the screensaver is running or not and regardless of which window has focus using:

```
./webkit2png --ignore-ssl-check -W 800 -H 600 -F -o MYSITE  http://www.lipsum.com/
```

You can use this with your existing Applescript - just put your `"frame-" & i` after the `MYSITE` part.

You will probably need to put the full path instead of `./webkit2png`, so, depending where you save the script, you may need to use something like `/Users/Geonemec/webkit2png --ignore-ssl-check ...`

You can get help on the options it accepts by running:

```
webkit2png -h
```

Comment: Sorry, I am not used to work with github. I saved the sourcecode as "webkit2png.py" is my root (first without the 3 lines added).
Then I used Terminal:

iMACAlbin:~ albinverhoeven$ python webkit2png.py -h
  File "webkit2png.py", line 464
    main()
       ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Further it is not clear how to integrate it in my script. Can you please explain me what to do?

Albin

Comment: webkit2png is running now. So far so good.

Integrating this in my script doesn't work yet.

This is my script for now:

set dFolder to "~/Desktop/screencapture/"

do shell script ("mkdir -p " & dFolder)

set i to 0
repeat 2 times
 tell application ./webkit2png --ignore-ssl-check -W 800 -H 600 -F -o MYSITE "frame-" & i http://www.geonemec.be/Geo/PR/GC70Z34.php
  delay 60 -- Wait for 60 seconds.
 end tell
 set i to i + 1
end repeat

(comment from applescript: Expected expression. found unknown token.)
What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
set dFolder to "~/Desktop/screencapture/"

do shell script ("mkdir -p " & dFolder)

set i to 1
repeat 2 times
    set DeTijd to time string of (current date)
    tell application "Terminal"
        activate
        do script ("webkit2png --ignore-ssl-check -F -o PR" & DeTijd & " " & "http://www.google.com")
    end tell
    delay 3600 -- Wait for 3600 seconds = 1 hour.
    set i to i + 1
end repeat
```

This works fine.
Tx for the help.